# How to build for iPhone with iOS 11.3 (15E216)?

Tags: ios, xcode

iPhone updated to 11.3 (15E216), but Xcode 9.3 Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport has 11.3 (15E217).  When I try to build for the physical device, I get the error "Could not locate device support files. This iPhone 6 is running iOS 11.3 (15E216), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode."   I've tried downloading older and newer versions of Xcode and none of them have 11.3 (15E216) DeviceSupport.  Is there something else to be done to allow me to build and install on the physical device?

Comment: Update your xcode to the last version

Answer (score 1):

You need Xcode 9.3 (9E145).
It supports 11.3. Just make sure you don't have/run a beta version of Xcode

Comment: We are in mid project with Xcode 8, do you know of any issues updating to Xcode 9 mid project?

Comment: We didn't have any issues so far. Couple little things with swift versions, but that was fine. But that was because we are still using swift 3. If you are using swift 4, that should be all good (can't guaranty depending on your project structure)

Comment: One thing actually, we found that upgrading device to 11.4 would block Xcode to build on these devices.

Comment: Even if you download the Beta 11.4 Image from Apple?

Comment: Nop, if you use the beta version that’s fine.